# Make the program stack not executable to stop code injection attack

Tags: c, callstack

Why is the stack executable? If the system forces the stack not to be executable and the text not to be writable, can the code injection attack be totally stopped?

Answer (score 1):

Even if the *stack* is not executable, it can be changed... causing the routine to return to a different address (since the return address is typically stored on the stack).

If the *heap* is executable, *data* can be written to contain valid op codes and the return address can be manipulated to return to that code.

Technologies such as DEP ([Data Execution Prevention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention)) and NX ([Never Execute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit)) can protect both the heap and the stack from execution.

Answer (score 0):

The main historical reason for executable stack is compatibility with a little-known and rarely-used GCC feature called "nested functions", which are equivalent to closures with automatic storage duration. If you take the address of a nested function, the program must actually generate a piece of code, called a trampoline, to load a hidden argument pointing to the data the actual function will use. This code lies on the stack.

Note that nested functions are not part of the C language, and there is no reason in the C language for the stack to be executable. C does not even require that code and data lie in a common address space. As such, implementations not aiming to support nonstandard extensions like nested functions should not provide executable stacks, as they compound the danger of any security flaws a program might have.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the stack executable?  Because the older x86 MMU (Memory Management Unit) only had 1 access bit per page.  The values were read-execute or read-write-execute.  The newer chips with DEP and NX added another bit per page to give fine grained control over execute permission.